# rails db:createができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, wsl

#### 解決したいこと

rails db:createができないので解決したいです。

#### 状態

・パソコンを買い替えたので、以前作業していたリポジトリをクローンしたばかりです。
・wsl2のubuntuを使用しています。
・rubyは 3.0.3
・railsは 6.0.4.6のバージョンを使っています。

#### これまでの操作

まず、今の開発環境にデータベースがないため、mysqlインストール後にrails db:createをしました。mysqlのインストールはマイクロソフトのサイトを参考にして行いました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database
その後rails db:createをした際以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
senseiy@senseIY-wsl:~/dictum/dictum$ rails db:create
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Couldn't create 'dictation_app_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
/home/senseiy/dictum/dictum/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/senseiy/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/home/senseiy/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/home/senseiy/dictum/dictum/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

このエラーで検索しましたが、どうやらAccess denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)のように表示されるようなのですが、私の場合、それが表示されません

```
# 私のエラー
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
# ググって出てくるエラー
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)　or YES
```

using passwordがついていないものは現在この方の記事しか見つけられませんでした

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545975/rails-app-denied-access-to-mysql-for-user-root-localhost

この方の場合、mysqlをアンインストールしてから再インストールしたら治ったようですが、自分の場合3回以上試したのですが直りません。
そこで以前のpc（windowsをつぶしてubuntuをいれたやつ）ではhomebrewを使ってインストールしていたためbrewコマンドでのインストールを試そうと考えたのですが、wsl2でmysqlをbrewコマンドでインストールしている記事が無かったため、一旦作業をストップしています。wsl2のubuntuでbrewコマンドでmysqlをインストールしても大丈夫でしょうか？また、そもそも別の部分がエラーの原因になっているのかもしれません。私のエラーの場合他にどのような原因が考えられるのでしょうか？

#### その他の原因として考えられることやこれまでに行った操作

・Windows 10 or 11 （WSL2）のUbuntuでsystemctlを利用する方法（systemdをPID1で動作させる方法）
https://snowsystem.net/other/windows/wsl2-ubuntu-systemctl/
こちらの記事を参考にgenieをインストールしました。
・gem の mysql2がインストール出来なかったのでnodeを15系にダウングレードしています。(最終的にmysql2のgemはインストール出来ました)

何かしらアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: railsではなくてコンソールから直接（mysqkコマンド等を利用して）インストールしたmysqlにアクセスすることはできますか？その際の認証情報やホストはrailsに設定したものになっていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。私の判断ミスでwsl2でbrewを使ってmysqlインストールしたことが原因？で状態を悪化させてしまいました。もう一度投稿し直したほうがいいと思い、質問を新しく投稿させて頂きました。この度はご迷惑をおかけしましてしまい、申し訳ございませんでした。